# Error 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf

I am running into the error `(413) Request Entity Too Large`. I have done some searching around and all I can see is that the `maxRecievedMessageSize` needs to be added to the binding and that binding needs to be added in the `bindingConfiguration`. I have taken those steps on both my client web.config and service web.config.

**Client**

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
...
<endpoint address="https://mysite.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
```

**WCF**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I do not have any `<service>` tags specified explicitly in my WCF web.config, but I have had success before not explicitly defining the tag. Are there any other issues that could be in play here?

Answer (score 0):

When using SSL/TLS, IIS can, under certain circumstances, buffer the entire HTTP request before passing it off to WCF. The default size of this buffer is only 48k, and if the buffer is exceeded IIS will return a 413 error.

To work around this, the size of the buffer has to be increased via the `uploadReadAheadSize` setting. In IIS 7.5, you can get to this setting via IIS Manager:

1. Select the web site in question under "Sites".
2. Launch "Configuration Editor".
3. Select Section: `system.webServer/serverRuntime`, From: `ApplicationHost.config`.
4. Set `uploadReadAheadSize` to the desired buffer size in bytes. Make sure it's larger than the largest request you might send.
5. Click "Apply".

For other IIS versions this setting may be in a different place.

There can be other reasons for getting a 413 as well, but this is the one I've run into. Of course, if you're not hosting the service in IIS this obviously wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

The `basicHttpBinding` you have defined in the service config file is not being used because it is not assigned to an endpoint.  In WCF 4.0+, you will get default endpoints with default bindings if you don't explicitly specify an endpoint - and the default binding for `http` is `basicHttpBinding`.  But this also means you will get the default values for the binding.

You can either add a service endpoint explicitly and assign your binding to it, or you can make your definition the **default** definition for `basicHttpBinding` by omitting the `name` attribute in the definition, like this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The above config snippet will then set your definition for `basicHttpBinding` as the default for any services uses `basicHttpBinding` in that application.